# Netty TLS exception PEER_DID_NOT_RETURN_A_CERTIFICATE

Tags: java, netty, tls1.2

I am using netty to establish a TLS connection in my app.
On the server side on SslContextBuilder when I set clientAuth to ClientAuth.REQUIRE

I keep getting this exception, even though I am sending the certs on the client side.

```
: error:100000c0:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:PEER_DID_NOT_RETURN_A_CERTIFICATE
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: error:100000c0:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:PEER_DID_NOT_RETURN_A_CERTIFICATE
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:459)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1414)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:945)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:141)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: error:100000c0:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:PEER_DID_NOT_RETURN_A_CERTIFICATE
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.sslReadErrorResult(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1106)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1066)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1132)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1175)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$1.unwrap(SslHandler.java:216)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1256)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeNonJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1171)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1204)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
```

Can someone suggest what I may be doing wrong.

Comment: On che client side you can enable debug `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake` to see what is REALLY sent, not what you think is happening. Apparently the server doesn't get any valid and trusted certificate from the client. Does the server trust the cert's issuer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> even though I am sending the certificate on the client side.

No. The message says otherwise.

The client will only send a certificate if it is signed by one of the trusted issuers mentioned by the server in its `CertificateRequest` message. It is not legal for the client to send any other certificate. Ergo your server's truststore doesn't trust any issuer of your client certificate.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir - I didn't realize the concept that the certificate should be present in TrustStore since the error was misleading (PEER_DID_NOT_RETURN_A_CERTIFICATE). Was chasing my tail trying to find out why client didn't send the certificate while the actual problem was that the truststore was incorrectly configured on the server side.